# Conditional format to show text based on specific values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to conditionally format a cell, (g4) to display particular number (text 1-5) on a list of a possible 1-15 different numbers in (F4).

I can conditionally format G4 to show a 3 when F4 is 7 by selecting G4 Conditional Format - Create New Rule =IF(F4="7", "3", F4)
I'm just not sure how to use multiple values.  All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from a range of possible text values, Conditional Formatting is not likely to give you what you're after. You'd be better off using an `Index(Match`, or a simple `Vlookup`.

It sounds like you're putting a number into `F4`, then you want `G4` to display a value based on that number. So go to an empty area of your worksheet, or a different worksheet, and build your list of values:

```
  Floor | Text
----------------
    1   | Cat
    4   | Dog
    7   | Mouse
    9   | Wombat
   13   | Indricothere
```

`Floor` here is the lowest value that should trigger a given result. Then in `G4`, you can create your `Vlookup`:

```
=VLOOKUP($F4,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,TRUE)
```

The formula will find the row that has the largest value that is less than `F4`, then return the value from column 2 of the same row.